# Get all record from nth bucket in Hive sql

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, bigdata, bucket

How to get all record from nth bucket in hive.

Select * from bucketTable from bucket 9;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this with different ways:

> ***Approach-1:* By getting the table `stored location` from `desc formatted <db>.<tab_name>`**
>
> **Then read the `9th bucket` file directly from `HDFS filesystem`.**

(or)

> ***Approach-2:* Using input_file_name()**
>
> **Then filter only `9th bucket` data by using filename**

**`Example:`**

**`Approach-1:`**

`Scala:`

```
val df = spark.sql("desc formatted <db>.<tab_name>")

//get table location in hdfs path
val loc_hdfs = df.filter('col_name === "Location").select("data_type").collect.map(x => x(0)).mkString

//based on your table format change the read format
val ninth_buk = spark.read.orc(s"${loc_hdfs}/000008_0*")

//display the data
ninth_buk.show()
```

`Pyspark:`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.sql("desc formatted <db>.<tab_name>")

loc_hdfs = df.filter(col("col_name") == "Location").select("data_type").collect()[0].__getattr__("data_type")

ninth_buk = spark.read.orc(loc_hdfs + "/000008_0*")

ninth_buk.show()
```

**`Approach-2:`**

`Scala:`

```
 val df = spark.read.table("<db>.<tab_name>")

//add input_file_name 
 val df1 = df.withColumn("filename",input_file_name())

#filter only the 9th bucket filename and select only required columns
val ninth_buk = df1.filter('filename.contains("000008_0")).select(df.columns.head,df.columns.tail:_*)

ninth_buk.show()
```

`pyspark:`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

 df = spark.read.table("<db>.<tab_name>")

df1 = df.withColumn("filename",input_file_name())

ninth_buk = df1.filter(col("filename").contains("000008_0")).select(*df.columns)

ninth_buk.show()
```

**Approach-2** will not be recommended if you have huge data as we need to filter through whole dataframe..!!

---

> **`In Hive:`**

```
set hive.support.quoted.identifiers=none;
select `(fn)?+.+` from (
                        select *,input__file__name fn from table_name)e 
 where e.fn like '%000008_0%';
```

Comment: Will this approach hold good if the table is stored as....df.write
   .bucketBy(50, "id")
   .saveAsTable("myHiveTable")

Comment: @baidyas, I think when we write data from spark -> hive bucketed table there are still some issues (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17729), it's better to write data using hive job to bucketed tables :)

Answer (score 0):

If it is a ORC table

```
SELECT * FROM orc.<bucket_HDFS_path>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from bucketing_table tablesample(bucket n out of y on clustered_criteria_column);
```

where `bucketing_table` is your bucket table name

```
n => nth bucket
y => total no. of buckets
```